# How to merge two or more rows by ignore null values in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table which looks like

```
col1  Col2  col3

NAME  123   Null

NAME  Null  243
```

I want to diplay them in one line.

```
col1      Col2      col3

NAME      123       243
```

I can't do a group by with C and D as they are not unique.

Is there another way of doing it in Oracle sql?

Comment: And if NAME has 3 or 4 different rows?

Comment: Name has more rows and col1 is always name ( i have more column like col2 and col3). I want to display them all in 1 line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query:

```
SELECT MAX(col1), MAX(Col2), MAX(col3)
FROM mytable
```

will return a *single* row that contains not null values for each field. If there is more than one not null value, then the maximum value will be selected.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT COL1,MAX(COL2),MAX(COL3)
FROM TableName
Group By COL1
```